# Bugs with saving data in cells by openpyxel in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, cell

I am working on a project to integrate the chat gpt api into my project. The chat responds with a description for the product in HTML format, and then the script records the response in the appropriate Excel cells. But the problem is that some descriptions are not recorded completely. They are torn to pieces! Here I took as an example the test script I made, with one of the descriptions. When launched, you will receive a table with cells that are individually filled. Some are written completely correctly, but most are cut off! I have absolutely no idea about this...

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time

book = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
sheet_ru = book['Лист1']
#sheet_ua = book['uk']

text = '<h2><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Посудомоечная машина Bosch SBV6ZDX49E: комфорт и надежность для вашей кухни</span></strong></h2> <p><span style="font-size:18px;">Хотите узнать, как сэкономить своё время и силы на мытье горы посуды? Встречайте посудомоечную машину Bosch SBV6ZDX49E – идеальное решение для каждой современной кухни. Сочетая в себе функциональность, стильный дизайн и передовые технологии, она станет незаменимым помощником для каждой хозяйки.</span></p> <h2><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Преимущества посудомоечной машины Bosch SBV6ZDX49E</span></strong></h2> <p><span style="font-size:18px;">Встраиваемая посудомоечная машина Bosch SBV6ZDX49E обладает рядом характеристик, которые делают её идеальным выбором: </span></p> <ol> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Высокая производительность и эффективность. Благодаря интеллектуальной системе управления, машина сама анализирует загрузку и оптимизирует режимы мойки, обеспечивая отличный результат каждый раз.</span></li> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Большая вместимость. Вместительная камера с регулируемой системой корзин позволяет удобно разместить посуду разных размеров и форм, в том числе большие кастрюли и сковороды.</span></li> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Минимальный шум. Благодаря шумоподавлению и специальным инновационным технологиям, работа машины происходит практически бесшумно, что создает комфорт во время мойки.</span></li> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Большой выбор программ. Различные режимы мойки позволяют выбрать оптимальный вариант для любой посуды и загрязнений, что обеспечивает идеальную чистоту и сохранность вашей сантехники.</span></li> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Экономия энергии и воды. Благодаря использованию инновационных технологий, посудомоечная машина Bosch SBV6ZDX49E является энергоэффективной и экологичной, помогая снизить расходы на коммунальные услуги и сохранить ресурсы планеты.</span></li> </ol> <h2><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Где купить посудомоечную машину Bosch SBV6ZDX49E в Днепре</span></strong></h2> <p><span style="font-size:18px;">Если вы ищете место, где можно купить посудомоечную машину Bosch SBV6ZDX49E в Днепре по привлекательной цене, интернет-магазин Foroom является оптимальным вариантом. Мы предлагаем широкий ассортимент бытовой техники от ведущих мировых производителей по выгодным ценам. Заказать машину для мытья посуды с доставкой в Днепре можно прямо сейчас – просто добавьте товар в корзину и оформите заказ на нашем сайте. Наша команда оперативно обработает ваш запрос и осуществит доставку в кратчайшие сроки. Не упустите возможность приобрести качественную посудомоечную машину Bosch SBV6ZDX49E по лучшей цене – выбирайте Foroom!</span></p>'

for i in range(1,10):
    sheet_ru[i][0].value = text

book.save("test.xlsx")
book.close()```
````

Any idea?

I tried to fill the cells with large text, hoping that it was just an excel limit, but no. I don't understand what the problem is... Maybe formatting?

For examle, text stopped 3/9 times with :

```
<h2><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Посудомоечная машина Bosch SBV6ZDX49E: комфорт и надежность для вашей кухни</span></strong></h2> <p><span style="font-size:18px;">Хотите узнать, как сэкономить своё время и силы на мытье горы посуды? Встречайте посудомоечную машину Bosch SBV6ZDX49E – идеальное решение для каждой современной кухни. Сочетая в себе функциональность, стильный дизайн и передовые технологии, она станет незаменимым помощником для каждой хозяйки.</span></p> <h2><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">Преимущества посудомоечной машины Bosch SBV6ZDX49E</span></strong></h2> <p><span style="font-size:18px;">Встраиваемая посудомоечная машина Bosch SBV6ZDX49E обладает рядом характеристик, которые делают её идеальным выбором: </span></p> <ol> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Высокая производительность и эффективность. Благодаря интеллектуальной системе управления, машина сама анализирует загрузку и оптимизирует режимы мойки, обеспечивая отличный результат каждый раз.</span></li> <li><span style="font-size:18px;">Большая вместимость. Вместительная камера с регулируемой системой корзин позволяет удобно разместить посуду разных размеров и форм, в том числе бол *here stopped*
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where exactly your example string gets truncated.

Comment: @kb2136 In different places. It is not something static. Try to run it, you will see that all 9 lines are recorded differently (sometimes they match). Although all should be as stated in the code. *i updated my ask*

Comment: Character limit is around 32k but this is not hard data limit: the application, in this case Excel can decide to truncate however it likes. You haven't specified the formatting for the cells but you need wrapping enabled and also a reasonable row height.

Comment: Use Xlwings instead

Comment: @moken Ty bro, u re the best!